# How to mock objects using MSTest?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking

I'm new with MSTest (Visual Studio 2010). 
Is there any integrated mocking framework that comes with VS2010?
Or is there any other good mocking framework that's easy to pick up that I could use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The VS 2010 doesn't come with mocking framework. But you can use either [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx)  (supports .NET 2.0 and 3.5), or [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)  (supports .NET 3.5 and .NET 4).

Both frameworks are good, but I prefer Moq, since it feels more natural to me. It uses fluent lambda  syntax which feels very clean to me once you get used to it.

Both frameworks are open source.

If you want a commercial one, go with [Typemock isolator](http://site.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-product). This framework can mock virtually anything but not free.

Comment: Thanks, I used FakeItEasy.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to take a look at [pex and moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/downloads.aspx). I haven't really played with it but if you want to stay faithful to MS tools, take a stab at it.

Comment: thanks.I'll have a look at them later. for now on, I'm just gonna stick with Moq.

Comment: @Attilah: Your question sounded like you wanted a MS Solution..Moq is really nice. Hope it meets your needs

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if mocking supported **yet** by Microsoft. I used [rhino mock](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) for type safety option, you can read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2007/04/26/choosing-a-mock-object-framework.aspx) just for a warm up.